# Frame centered with foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I try to use foundation from my CSS old HTML.
I have a frame for the login form :
[image: connexion window]
I tried to use centered `<div class="large-4-centered columns">` but It's not centered.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foundation-framework-/rxy0qak4n8w)
and used :

```
<div class="row">         
      <div class="small-centered large-6 columns small-12">
          <div class="row">
              // content goes here
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```